# How to show only the subcategories of selected category

Tags: php, html

I have a list of Categories with sub categories, If I select any category mean Only the subcategories of that selected category need to show in sub category list.

**MY CODE**

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label class="form-control-label">Categories</label>

            <select name="categories_id" class="form-control" required>
                
                <option value="">Select Categories</option>
                
                <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM categories");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    if($row['id'] == $set_scatidd){
                       echo "<option value=".$row['id']." selected>".$row['categories']."</option>";
                    }else{
                       echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['categories']."</option>";
                    } 
                } ?>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label class="form-control-label md_rl">Sub-Categories</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="sub_categories_id" required>
                <option>Select Sub-Categories</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My database table**

categories Table column

**id ,categories**

sub_categories Table column

**id ,categories_id ,sub_categories**

These are my categories and sub-categories table

Comment: You need Ajax or JavaScript. This needs to be done on the client side not in PHP

Comment: Give jQuery a try.  https://jsfiddle.net/ebopq16q/